# buildrpm fails when cross building C++ for 32-bit ARM (from x86-64)

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling, rpmbuild

I successfully compiled C++ code for a Raspberry Pi (ARM architecture).

Such binaries have a `file` command return the following :

`usr/local/company/product/this: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=9fe73c254b317e239758e4445d12b8441a3cb13e, not stripped`

I now  wish to generate RPM packages (not `.deb` packages, real `.RPM` packages!).
I've tried many `--target` and `spec`'s file `buildarch` combinations without much success.
Tried `armv7l`, `arm-linux-gnueabihf`, `arm-linux` ...

Same result is returned by rpmbuild :

```
Building target platforms: arm-unknown-linux
Building for target arm-unknown-linux
error: No compatible architectures found for build
```

I'm compiling from an x86_64 Ubuntu. The destination architecture is arm-linux-gnueabihf.

I call rpmbuild as follow :
`rpmbuild -bb --target armv7l myfile.spec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my RHEL 7 computer, the `/usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc` includes several ARM variants:
`armv3l`, `armv4b`, `armv4l`, `armv4tl`, `armv5tel`, `armv5tejl`, `armv6l`, `armv7l`, `armv7hl`, `armv7hnl`. I guess your file will have a similar selection, and thus include the `armv7l` option you selected.

I found that for cross-packaging, running `rpmbuild --target _target_` was not enough. I also had to use a `setarch _target_` wrapper around the build command.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add your arm architecture (displayed by uname -m) to /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`GOARCH=amd64` or `arm64`
used the command:

```
rpmbuild ... --define="GOARCH ${GOARCH}"
```

spec file should include this content

```
%if %{GOARCH} == "amd64"
BuildArch:      x86_64
%endif
%if %{GOARCH} == "arm64"
BuildArch:      aarch64
%endif
```